# Simple keras model shape issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Starting to learn Keras and TensorFlow.  Why is the shape wrong, and how can I fix it?

(temperature input to predict electricity load output)

```
load = data.loc[:35063,'Load'].values
temp = data.loc[:35063,'Temperature'].values

load.shape
(35064,)

from keras.layers import Input,Dense
input_tensor = Input(shape=(35064,))
output_tensor = Dense(1)(input_tensor)
from keras.models import Model
model = Model(input_tensor,output_tensor)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mape')

model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)        (None, 35064)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 35065     
=================================================================
Total params: 35,065
Trainable params: 35,065
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

model.fit(temp,load,verbose=True)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_13 to have shape (35064,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

When I print the shape of my arrays, they are both `(35064,)`.  Why does Keras think the input array is `(1,)`?

Answer (score 0):

In the line,

```
load.shape()
# Output is ( 35064 , )
```

The number 35064 shows the number pf samples in the `load` array. The subarrays don't have a definite shape and hence there is a `,` after 35064. The unknown dimension in Keras is treated as None. So the fix could be,

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None,))
# Should fix the problem!
```

> The None dimension can handle any other dimension value. In Keras, the input shape must not include the num_of_samples.

The model which gave the error would have input shape as ( 35064 , 35064 )

The fixed error would result in the input shape of ( 35064 , None ).

Answer (score 0):

The first dimension of your array is always the samples dimension, which is not something you have to put in the input_shape. You can reshape your array to (35064, 1), which means that you have to change your input shape.

Use this:

```
load = load.reshape((35064, 1))
temp = temp.reshape((35064, 1))

input_tensor = Input(shape=(1,))
```